# which path will be appended to sys.path when i run python3 src/b.py?

Tags: python-3.6

Which paths are added to `sys.path` when the command is run, what are the factors that affect it?

My Python version is 3.6.4, and I also tried it on version 3.7.

Directory structure is

```
.
├── __init__.py
└── src
    ├── a.py
    └── b.py
```

code is

```py
# a.py
class A: pass

# b.py
from sys
print(sys.path)

from src.a import A
a = A()
print(a)
```

I tried to run `python3 src/b.py` on two machines with the same Python version. One of them did not report an error and the other error occurred.

In the correct running result, there are two directories in `sys.path`, one is the current directory and the other is the `src` directory; 
The correct output is:

```
['/home/work/test/testimport/src', '/home/work/test/testimport',...]
<src.a.A object at 0x7f8b71535ac8>
```

The wrong result is:

```
['/home/work/test/testimport/src', ...]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/b.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.a import A
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

`sys.path` contains only the `src` directory.

Which path will be appended to sys.path when i run python3 src/b.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`src` is indeed not a module (does not contain `__init__.py`) and it does not matter if it is in your path or not. In addition, `b.py` "sees" the directory it is in (`src`) anyway, so

```
from a import A
```

would work no matter where are you executing `B` from (`python3 /path/to/src/b.py`) should work. Note even if you did create

```
`src/__init__.py`
```

your `b.py` would fail if you did not add the directory `src` to your path (or **PYTHONPATH**, which is the recommended way to add python modules to your path).